# RxJava2 Interval + subject

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm trying to create a chain of interval and subject. I have a connectable interval, like this:

```
var inteval =
    ConnectableObservable.interval(WITHOUT_DELAY, ONE_SECOND, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .publish()
        .refCount()
```

And a some subject, where several times in second I send some values:

```
 val subject: Subject<Double> = PublishSubject.create()
```

I'm trying to create some chair, where every second I will wait value from subject. I made different attempts, but still have misunderstanding. Maybe somebody know the correct way to resolve it? Now I have two different subscribers and general variable, and I afraid, that in some moment when interval will write a new value, subject will read a bad value.

Comment: I don't understand. How are the subject and the interval supposed to be related? Do you want some periodic activity and manual triggering?

Comment: @akarnokd, I have the two streams of data: first from subject and second from interval. I want to take every each second one value from subject stream

Comment: Do you mean like the pattern in [`sample`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#sample-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)?

Comment: @akarnokd This is very cool example and it do almost needed, but I want sync by interval. In app I have several processes, which listening the clock from interval. Wwill be great, if you know these case too

Comment: Please check the other overloads or methods and see which fits your requirement.

Comment: @akarnokd anyway you answer very cool. let accept it like correct) please add it below

Comment: You can answer your own question :)